# Polymer readOnly access private setter for given property

Tags: javascript, properties, polymer-1.0, readonly

I am aware you can set a readOnly property by using the generated setter: `_setMyProp(newValue)`

But what if I don't know the name of the property before-hand? Is there any way to access the setter for a given property? My current solution is mapping property names to their setter functions:

```
_setters: {
    type: Object,
    value: {
        prop1 : function(newVal) { this._setProp1(newVal); },
        prop2 : function(newVal) { this._setProp2(newVal); }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

### Update

For more context, this is the function that calls _setters. This function should ideally not use any actual property names. This is what I meant by "don't know the name of the property before-hand"

```
load: function(data, key) {
    if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
        if (key) {
            this._setters[key].bind(this)(data);
        } else {
            _.each(this._setters, function(setter, key) {
                setter.bind(this)(data[key]);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
},
```

The element behaves like [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta) and loads data from a global object when it's ready, and sets all it's properties.

```
ready: function() {
    this.load(_data);
},
```

But it must also load specific properties when an ajax response comes in, for each attached element.

```
_els.forEach(function(el) {
    el.load(key, _data[key]);
});
```

I'm trying to make it as easy as possible to define more properties later on. Polymer's `this.set('propName', 'value');` would be perfect but does not work for readOnly properties.

If I should just scrap this entirely and go a different route, I'd also be open to that advice.

### Update 2

My solution for lack of a better one was to abandon `readOnly` and just use `this.set`

This is what `load` looks like now:

```
load: function(data, property) {
    if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
        if (property) {
            this.set(property, data[property]);
        } else {
            Object.keys(this.properties).forEach(function(property) {
                this.set(property, data[property]);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the name beforehand?

Comment: Hmm. How would you use `_setters` without knowing the property name beforehand?

Comment: I'm realizing this is a complex question. Updated to include more context as to what I'm doing.

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to do this, but for a readOnly property you can set it's value by calling it's ```_set<Property>( value )``` method, but you need to declare the property before that :/